# A word or phrase to describe indirect relegion insult

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Suppose I follow a different relgion/faith than person X. X had a bad experience with a person Y who follows the same faith as mine. In a conversation between me, X and other friends, X is upset about the incident and starts passing remarks about Y, and that Y follows that particular faith, mocking Y's relegious gestures and clothing, ... etc. All this while X is (or acted as) completely oblivious to the fact I am sitting there and follow Y's religion.

He does not say all people who follow that faith are bad. But he passes remarks such as `f word christian/jew/mulsim/hindu.. trash` and so on.

Now I follow that faith, and I felt hurt. Although not religous myself, but I still have emotional connection wtih my faith. But questioning myself, I was wondering what does X do to make me feel hurt? Does `indirect insult` describes it enough, given it has to do with religion?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to view those insults as anything but direct! But if this were an SE about advice or psychology instead of English, I'd post an answer that X was indulging in [transference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transference) that would need to be addressed based on the circumstances and how well you know X.

Comment: You could say that person X **disrespected** you, because he said those things knowing you followed Y's religion. Are you looking for something specifically referencing an insult?

Answer (score 1):

a good word for an >indirect insult< is:

***to slight***

NOTE - you seem to be fairly forgiving of your friend's extremely rude and offensive terms (f'ing)

- a slight would be something closer to a '**microagression**' not the extreme offense you would take from someone directly and belligerently attacking your group or religion

I list -slight- because, your question seemed to be looking for a more mild term than most would apply to the behavior you describe.

> [Oxford Dictionary definition of ***Slight*** (as a verb and noun)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slight)
>
> *(note, there is the common adjective meaning of slight , meaning Small in degree; inconsiderable: or : thin or slender)*
>
> VERB [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1 - Insult (someone) by treating or speaking of them without proper respect or attention:
>
> ‘*he was desperate not to slight a guest*’
>
> 2 ...
>
> NOUN
>
> - An insult caused by a failure to show someone proper respect or attention:
>
> ‘*an unintended slight can create grudges*’
>
> ‘*he was seething at the slight to his authority*’

To make it apply to religion you'd need to bring that up (unfotunately it's not all in one)

i.e.  I took his comments about Thor being a 'lightweight', as a personal slight. He should have known that I've worshipped Thor for millenium.

Comment: I'm not so sure.. "F'ing Thorian trash" is a bit stronger than a slight. A slight would be complaining about your failure to show up to play baseball on Thursday (you were actually drinking mead all day as any Proper Thorian would do).

Comment: @Spencer I'll edit my comments to make it clearer .. although,  it's a tricky one.. usually once someone starts using the F word they're on a rant, turning up the volume a few notches... still.. we don't tolerate that sort of stuff these days for good reasons.

Comment: @Tom22 The F word is used with insults, outside of rants, plenty. It's more prevalent in the younger genreations.

Comment: I don't think the question is about the mildness of the insult. It's about the indirectness or obliqueness.